# Select múltiplo

Tags: php, html

Estou com um problema para obter os resultados de um `select` múltiplo, pois ele não vem com todo o nome quando se trata de um nome composto exemplo.

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo teste</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab verifica</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel mais</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Porém quando obtenho a resposta do retorno aparece apenas:

```
"Volvo", "Saab", "Opel" e "Audi"
```

A parte composta do nome não esta aparecendo.
Era para aparecer em meu resultado se eu selecionar "Volvo Teste" e não apenas "Volvo".

Comment: Quando você envia o formulário, são enviados apenas os `value` da options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você envia um `select` você não obtém o seu `name`, apenas a propriedade `value` das opções selecionadas como o sam bem mencionou no comentário.

Até mais e seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow BR

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta, no caso eu estou enviando via $_POST para outro formulario, ele vem de um SQL onde preenche meu select multiplo corretamente, mas qdo envio para o outro form ele vem Cortado só a primeira palavra que aparece. 
<select name="operadora[]" id="operadora" class=" form-control"  multiple="multiple">
 <?php echo $oper;?>
</select>

Comment: Obrigado amigos,
verifiquei o problema depois que vcs falaram, estava bem aqui qdo recebo do SQL
$oper = $oper . "<option value=" . $exec->Fields['operadora']->Value . ">" . utf8_encode($exec->Fields['operadora']->Value) . "</option>";

adicionei uma ' depois do . "<option value="  ' e antes do  ' >"

valeu

Answer (score 1):

Coloco no seu atributo **value** do Html o nome completo, pois esse atributo é o responsável pelo retorno e não o que você escreveu para exibição na página. 
Com certeza o que esta retornando para você neste código acima é o que esta escrito dentro do **value**.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <select name="cars" multiple>
    <option value="Volvo teste">Volvo teste</option>
    <option value="Saab verifica">Saab verifica</option>
    <option value="Opel mais">Opel mais</option>
    <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito obrigado,